# Ubuntu Laptop - Disable graphics card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, graphics-card

I buyed a laptop with a good processor (Ryzen 9 4900H) and with a Graphic Card (RTX 2060) and this is a great machine, but I don't have **enough battery life**...

I was wondering if there was a way to **permanent disable my GPU** because the integrated GPU Raedon Vega is *quite comfortable for my work*, and only **reable it** when I want **to play** ...

I'm looking for some *hard way* as when I'll restart my compu, **the GPU will always be disabled**...

I didn't find nothing on the internet, so maybe this is impossible?

Comment: The "amdgpu" driver deals with both the APU and the GPU I suppose?

Comment: Check if https://codeflu.blog/2013/04/25/disabling-discrete-amd-graphics-card-in-linux/ works.  If so, it shouldn't be hard to do this on boot.